Is it possible to know the family of functions a neural network approximates?
Is it possible somehow to find which family of functions a particular network approximates?
For example, I have some directed graph and I use its vertices as artificial neurons (as simple McCulloch & Pitts neurons), and I want to know the class of functions which it can approximate

Can you be more specific about what you mean by "class of functions"? Do you have in mind any classes?

Maybe this answers your question?
